# remove NaNs from ExpressionSet

Tags: r

Sometimes in microarray analysis, some datasets contain `NaN` values, I need to remove `NaNs` from `gset` to `ex` matrix will be without `NaNs` too. How to remove `NaNs` from `ExpressionSet` (`gset`)?

(`gset` class is `ExpressionSet`).

I would be very pleased if you could guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is called MyDataset you can pass it inside na.omit function and save the output as MyProcessedDataset. e.g. below

```
MyProcessedDataset <- na.omit(MyDataset)
```

Not sure what is your dataset name though, in this case. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.
I convert ExpressionSet into a Matrix, following replace NaNs with zero and convert the matrix into ExpressionSet again.